# How to save data as logs in firebase in non-realtime manner so that the cost of updating and reading those data in not so high?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am making an IOS app and I want to save the notification logs of the user in firebase itself, but I don't want to make it realtime since the firebase SDK makes all the user-related data available to the client locally (Correct me if I am wrong). This would mean that the notification logs are also available to the user in realtime which will increase the cost because RTDB is expensive. Hence, I want to figure out a way that I can store the logs within the database but without being realtime. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no obligation to use Firestore in a "realtime" manner.  You can simply `set()` documents, then just [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) them on the client as needed, which will avoid the need for the client to constantly read new data, if that is what you're trying to avoid.  `get()` is not "realtime" - it's a one-time fetch made a the time it's invoked.  If you do want realtime listeners, then use the [specific APIs](http://aws%20cloudfront%20create-invalidation%20--distribution-id%20E24TVS5WJ15B6M%20--paths) for that.